# All Values of a Complex expression

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am asked to find all values to $$\left(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}\right)^{1+i}$$

I do not know how to approach a power with complex part. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I edited my equation to add the brackets signifying the whole fraction is to the exponent. Which leaves $$ (e^{\frac{-i \pi}{4}})^{1+i} $$ which is what I had difficulties with. The exponential to the power of a complex.

Answer (score 2):

Since 
$$ (1-i) = \sqrt{2}\,e^{-\pi i/4} $$
we have:
$$ (1-i)^i = e^{\frac{i}{2}\log 2+2k\pi} e^{\pi/4} = (\cos(\log\sqrt{2})+i\sin(\log\sqrt{2}))\,e^{2k\pi+\pi/4}$$
with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
$(1-i) = \sqrt(2)e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Now let $ln(k) = i\cdot ln(1-i)$. Can you complete from here?

Comment: Not quite my difficulty is with the power (1+i).

Answer (score 1):

Using $1 - i = \sqrt{2} e^{-\pi i/4}$ it is seen that
\begin{align}
\frac{(1-i)^{1+i}}{\sqrt{2}} &= \left( \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}} \right) (1-i)^{i} \\
&= e^{-\pi i/4} \cdot (\sqrt{2})^{i} e^{\pi/4} \\
&= e^{\pi/4} \cdot e^{-\pi i/4} e^{i \ln(\sqrt{2})} \\
&= e^{\pi/4} \cdot e^{-i (\pi/4 - \ln(2)/2)} \\
&= e^{\pi/4} \left[ \cos\left(\frac{\pi - 2 \ln(2)}{4}\right) - i \sin\left(\frac{\pi - 2 \ln(2)}{4}\right) \right]. 
\end{align}